# Flatmap in RxSwift Swift 5

Tags: swift, rx-swift, swift5

How come this works, which was written before Swift 5?

```
viewmodel
      .postSeekerAvatar(data: data)    
      .flatMap {
        self.viewmodel.updateSeeker(withFirstName: params.firstName, lastName: params.lastName, isBusiness: params.isBusiness, abn: "none", address: params.address)
      }
      .subscribe(onSuccess: { (_) in
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: SegueConstants.toProfileForm, sender: self)
      }) { (error) in
        SVProgressHUD.showDismissableInfo(with: error.message)
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

But once I updated to Swift 5, the code does not throw an error but when I use the `.flatMap {}` closure it throws an error stating

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'll have to provide much more context. What are the different return types of you methods?

Comment: the returns are the same type, just different data. essentially my question is how come .flatMap{} throws an error after I updated to swift 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the compiler cannot deduce the type of your flatMap returned value.

Is easily fixed adding the type after the flatMap:

```swift
   .flatMap { _ -> Observable<Whatever> in 
       ...
   }
```